# Base class constraint on generic class specifying the class itself

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter, generic-constraints

Yesterday, I was explaining C#'s generic constraints to my friends. When demonstrating the `where T : CLASSNAME` constraint, I whipped up something like this:

```
public class UnusableClass<T> where T : UnusableClass<T>
{
    public static int method(T input){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And was really surprised to see it compile. After a bit of thinking, however, I figured it was perfectly legal from the point of view of the compiler - `UnusableClass<T>` is as much of a class as any other that can be used in this constraint.

However, that leaves a couple of questions: how can this class ever be used? Is it possible to

1. Instantiate it?
2. Inherit from it?
3. Call its static method `int method`?

And, if yes, how?

If any of these *is* possible, what would the type of `T` be?

Comment: Hmm.. smells like homework.

Comment: @JamieKeeling: no, not really. I'm just interested if it's even possible =) My friends were totally sure that it's not, but I had my doubts...

Comment: I am considering how to improve the title. It's kind of - haha - generic right now...

Comment: @J.Steen: I know, sorry... But I couldn't think of anything else when I was asking =)

Comment: Sometimes it's hard finding the right terminology for a piece of code. When you do, feel free to edit the title with the correct phrase so people searching for it can find it in the future. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: is it better now? =)

Comment: @Mints97 Definitely! Nice.

Comment: It's a good pattern for recursive types, as trees and graphs. It becomes an anti-pattern in pretty much every other case, where it complicates the code and make it less readable. I remember the code base at my previous work, where this was used everywhere. It still makes me shiver.

Comment: Related: [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Isn't this just F-bounded Polymorphism?

Comment: For an in the wild [example](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/master/Source/Csla/BusinessBase.cs), the [CSLA](http://www.cslanet.com/) business object framework uses this pattern, for precisely the reason mentioned in J. Steen's answer.

Comment: A quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification might be worthwile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well.

```
public class Implementation : UnusableClass<Implementation>
{
}
```

is perfectly valid, and as such makes

```
var unusable = new UnusableClass<Implementation>();
```

and

```
UnusableClass<Implementation>.method(new Implementation());
```

valid.

So, yes, it can be instantiated by supplying an inheriting type as the type parameter, and similarly with the call to the static method. It's for instance useful for tree-like structures where you want to generically specify the type of children the node has, while it being the same type itself.

Answer (score 15):

This approach is widely used in Trees and other Graph-like structures. Here you say to compiler, that T has API of UnusableClass. That said, you can implement TreeNode as follows:

```
public class TreeNode<T>
    where T:TreeNode<T>
{
    public T This { get { return this as T;} }

    public T Parent { get; set; }

    public List<T> Childrens { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddChild(T child)
    {
        Childrens.Add(child);
        child.Parent = This;
    }

    public virtual void SetParent(T parent)
    {
        parent.Childrens.Add(This);
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public class BinaryTree:TreeNode<BinaryTree>
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> If any of these is possible, what would the type of T be?

They are all possible, and you are the one who is gonna determine what is the type of `T`.For example let's assume there is a type that inherits from `UnusableClass<T>`

```
class Foo : UnusableClass<Foo> { }
```

Now you can instantiate `UnusableClass<Foo>` because `Foo` satisfies the constraint:

```
UnusableClass<Foo> f = new UnusableClass<Foo>();
```

Then the type of `T` become `Foo` and if you try to call `method` you need to pass an instance of `Foo`.